# Creating Planner Tasks with Dynamic Checklist Items

Tags: workflow, power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to pull together some automation to allow a set of recurring tasks to be created on a regular schedule. The source of this data is an excel file stored in Sharepoint. I have the bones of the workflow together and it's successfully creating tasks and adding a checklist item, using 'Create a Task' and 'Update a task'.

Where I'm getting stuck is a way to utilise the source file to apply the custom checklist items. The reason they're custom is I'm building some custom reporting from the planner tasks in Power BI where I'm using the checklist as a way to designate the Main and backup staff member completing tasks, as they run off a roster.

I've tried playing around with creating variables (using 'initialise variable' and 'append to array variable'), but I can't see a way to "join" the source data to the task that's being created.  I've also been trying to follow examples in this website, again with no luck.

The source table looks like this. What I'm hoping to do is use the 'Checklist1' and 'Checklist2' values as the checklist items on each corresponding tasks. This could change over time as well, to include a 3rd checklist item (so any solution can hopefully be scalable)

| Title | Description | Checklist 1 | Checklist 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DD Daily Run | Testing Daily Run Task | Main: Steve | Backup: Ben |
| Collect Payment | Collecting Payment Run | Main: Ben | Backup: Steve |

Working Attempt

[image]

[image]

Simple working example

[image]